# VMware workstation pro doesn't autofit server VMs in main desktop

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player, esxi

New to Windows 11, I came across a very weird and annoying problem.

I'm using "VMware® Workstation 16 Pro", and then using it to connect to server "File > connect to server" which is "VMWare ESXI 7".

I have the following options set:

- Edit> Preferences > Display > Autofit > Autofit Guest
- Edit> Preferences > Display > Autofit > Autofit Windows
- Edit> Preferences > Display > Full screen > Autofit Guest

So, when I try to full-screen the guest, it just simply doesn't work, it remains a small window in the middle of the screen, doesn't full screen, and doesn't scale.

However, when I move the guest to a separate connected monitor (in a multi-monitor setup connected to my laptop), it works fine and the guest perfectly autofits and scales.

So it is very weird, on the same laptop, it works fine on the extended screen but not on the main screen (so it is an indication that my setup on the workstation is fine).

- my OS is Windows 11 Pro 22H2,
- my laptop is Dell XPS 17 inch,
- obviously the resolution of the main display (my laptop) is different from the extended monitor,
- I have vmware tools (the latest version) installed on my guest,
  my server is ESXI 7,
- I'm using VMware® Workstation 16 Pro (it is 32-bit, it seems that's the only version)

any help is really appreciated

Comment: Preferences > Display > Autofit > Autofit Guest  ...   Preferences > Display > Autofit > Autofit Windows   ..... These conflict.  Only choose ONE.

Comment: after changing it, the problem is still there, any other advise mate?

Comment: I am not sure.  I have reinstalled VMware Workstation to fix issues but not with VMware V16

Comment: what is the OS that you're connecting to, ESXi 7?  There's really not much to see there except the VGA status and basic config screens.

Comment: I re-installed the vmware few times, but the problem still exist, it is ESXI 7